# Reading and writing Integers from/to file in Java

Tags: java, integer, set

I've just created app for reading integers from file into Set, and I have a question , when i have in my input file numbers -5 5 2 8 9 1 4 55 70, it saves the numbers into Set this way-[1, 2, 4, 5, 70, 55, 8, 9], why it is like this? I want it to avoid duplicity - this is OK but I want to save the numbers first way.

```
    Set<Integer> zoznam = new HashSet();
    int index = 0;
    FileReader fr;
    fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int i = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line);
        String[] items = line.split(" ");
        int[] c = new int[items.length];
        for (int q = 0; q < items.length; q++) {
            c[q] = Integer.parseInt(items[q]);
            zoznam.add(c[q]);
        }
    }
    return zoznam;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set`, generally, does not guarantee any order. If you want to maintain the order you need to use a specialized implementation, e.g., a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), the retains the order of insertion.

Comment: Thank you mate!! It helped me a lot

Comment: @DebosmitRay `TreeSet` is a `SortedSet` - it will sort the inserted items and display them according to their natural ordering. For the input given by the OP (5 5 2 8 9 1 4 55 70), the output would be 1 2 4 5 8 9 55 70. A `LinkedHashSet`, on the contrary, preserves the order of insertion.

Comment: So sorry. I had misread. I thought the OP wanted the elements to be ordered, not preserve ordering. Sorry about that, @Mureinik.